# Как включить возможность печатать специальные символы в Linux?

Tags: linux, клавиатура

Открываю любой текстовой редактор и пытаюсь ввести символ удерживая alt и циферки из NumLock секции. Никакого символа. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Всё делаете не так. Этот способ для Windows. В линуксе по-другому, а как именно зависит от дистрибутива и в некоторых случаях даже от версии.

Comment: Символы не невидимые, а специальные.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зажимаем Ctrl + Shift + U и не отпуская записываем HEX код от символа.

К примеру. Узнаём с помощью Python интерпретатора что за символ находится под кодом 24312.

```
chr(24312)
```

Ответ такой : '廸'

Переводим это значение в hex :

```
hex(24312)
```

Ответ такой : '0x5ef8'

Теперь открываем текстовой редактор и прописываем след **зажимая** Ctrl + Shift:

5ef8.

В итоге введённая строка будет такой : U5EF8.

Отпускаем Ctrl + Shift и перед нами китайский символ.